# How can I remove a Mortise Lock and deadbolt from a door?

Tags: doors, removal, lock

I got an old door from a junk yard that I'm trying to reuse. The door is going to end up being sliding barn door so I have no use for its existing door knob and lock mechanisms. From what I can tell the lock is a mortise lock, and I figured out how to remove door knobs, however I can't seem to figure out how to remove the deadbolt which appears to be connected the interior lock mechanism also preventing it from coming out.  There were two screws on each side of the deadbolt lock that I removed, but even after using a chisel and hammer I am unable to remove it.  Does anyone know how I remove this and/or the interior mechanism

[image: dead bolt lock]
[image: lock mechanism]

Comment: That looks like a screw just about the dead bolt in your second picture. Have you tried removing that?

Comment: If you do manage remove it in good condition, sell it back to the junk yard or find a local vendor. Old brass parts like that are worth a few bucks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove the key set section as pictured on the left. It may be very corroded and require a bit of persuasion to split the halves and remove from the deadbolt assembly.  Once you have removed the keyway from both sides, there should be nothing but a couple of screws on the striker/jam plate holding the bolt assembly.

Comment: Removal of dead bolt was the main thing I was unable to figure out.  But I had my father-in-law take a look at it and it ended up being threaded into the door and the dead bolt assembly set had to be unscrewed like a giant screw in order to be removed which then in-turn released the rest of the interior lock pieces.